# What values to put in my properties file to get an IOException while loading?

Tags: java, junit, properties, ioexception

I am reading a file from its classpath in Java project.

Sample Code:

```
      public static Properties loadPropertyFile(String fileName) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();    
        InputStream inputStream = PropertyReader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);

        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                properties.load(inputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Property file: [" + fileName + "] not found in the classpath");
        }
        return properties;
      }
```

It's working fine. I am  writing Junit tests for this code. How can I create a scenario for `IOException` in `properties.load(inputStream)`?

What values should I put in my properties.file to get `IOException`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered a mocking framework? Mock the `new` operator for Properties to return a mock implementation that throws `IOException` when its `load` method is called.

mockitio and powermockito will allow you to do this.

Answer (score 3):

When you look into the implementation of `Properties::load`, you find out that the class never throws the exception explicitly. The only way to trigger an `IOException` would be to hand an `InputStream` that throws this exception upon invoking the input stream's `read` method.

Do you have control over the `PropertyReader` class? One way to emulate this error would be to [instrument this class loader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) to return an errornous `InputStream` for a given test value of `fileName` to throw an `IOException`. Alternatively, you could make the method more flexible by changing the signature to:

```
public static Properties loadPropertyFile(String fileName) {
  return loadPropertyFile(fileName, PropertyReader.class);
}

public static Properties loadPropertyFile(String fileName, ClassLoader cl) {
  // your code...
}
```

with handing a class loader:

```
class TestLoader extends ClassLoader {
  @Override
  public InputStream getResourceAsStream() {
    return new InputStream() {
      @Override
      public byte read() throws IOException {
        throws new IOException();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You cannot add specific characters to the properties file that cause an `IOException` as the `InputStream` only reads bytes. Any encoding-realted problem will instead result in an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Since what the OP wants to test is the load method in Properties class wouldn't it be simpler to create a Properties with a Overriden load method that actually throws the IOException?

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi - Yes ... but how do you get the code that is being tested to *use* the custom `Properties` subclass?  That approach doesn't solve the problem.  If you want to modify/replace the `Properties` object *for test purposes*, the way to do it is using a mocking framework that can *inject* a mock properties class without modifying the source code of the class you are testing.  See the accepted answer.

Comment: @StephenC I agree with you that this is not worth to modify your code, but the accepted answer did not provide a sample code that we could have a idea on how to cover de IOException branch.

Answer (score 0):

One way of forcing the `load` call to throw `IOException` is to pass a closed stream. If you can refactor your method to accept a `InputStream` you can pass a closed stream to the method and check whether it is throwing an exception.

That said, Unit Tests are supposed to cover the code you write. It seems to me you are testing whether `load` throws an exception if the input stream has an error. Which is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old thread, but since I recently ran into the same problem and based on [Rafael Winterhalter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32755175/1630619) I came up with this test:

```
@Test
void testFailLoadProjectFile() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    final var method = LogGeneratorComponent.class.getDeclaredMethod("loadProjectProperties", Properties.class);

    Assertions.assertTrue(Modifier.isPrivate(method.getModifiers()), "Method is not private.");

    method.setAccessible(true);

    final var obj = new LogGeneratorComponent();

    Assertions.assertThrows(InvocationTargetException.class, () -> method.invoke(obj, new Properties() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5663506788956932491L;

        @Override
        public synchronized void load(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final InputStream is) throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("Invalid properties implementation.");
        }
    }), "An InvocationTargetException should have been thrown, but nothing happened.");
}
```

And this is my actual method:

```
private static Properties loadProjectProperties(final Properties properties) {
    try (final var is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("project.properties")) {
        properties.load(is);
        return properties;
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException("Error while reading project.properties file.", e);
    }
}
```

Obviously OP can customize it to receive a fileName parameter and make it public in order to have a simpler test.

Comment: So ... in order to use this approach, the OP would have to modify the application that they are testing so that the Properties object to be loaded is passed as an argument.  I don't think that is a good idea.  (Indeed, given a choice between doing that to achieve 100% test coverage, and not covering the `IOException` branch, I would say that the latter choice is definitely the better one.)

Comment: In my case since my method is private it was not painfull to pass the Properties as a parameter, but I agree with you that since in the OP case with a public method that can have inumerous calls leaving the IOException branch would be a better choice.

Answer (score -2):

Empty or Invalid `fileName` parameter.

Comment: surely that'll cause the exception on the `InputStream` line, instead of on the `.load` call?

Answer (score -2):

pass a blank string as file name

Comment: I want exception in `properties.load(inputStream)`

Comment: We had a similar issue to reproduce, The scenario was "what will happen if n/w drops when the program is in the middle of reading a file".

Comment: We did that by actually placing the file to be read in network share drive.